# extract tweets from a text file (python)

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweets

Sorry, I am just trying to store 'id_str' from each tweet to a new list called ids[]..
but getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "extract_tweet.py", line 17, in 
>       print tweet['id_str']
>   KeyError: 'id_str'

My code is:

```
import json
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
tweets = []
for line in open (sys.argv[1]):
try:
  tweets.append(json.loads(line))
except:
  pass
ids = []
for tweet in tweets:
ids.append(tweet['id_str'])
```

Comment: Print out `tweets` and make sure it is what you are expecting. Does it have `'id_str'` key?

Comment: u'contributors', u'truncated', u'text', u'in_reply_to_status_id', u'id', u'favorite_count', u'source', u'retweeted', u'coordinates', u'entities', u'in_reply_to_screen_name', u'id_str', u'retweet_count', u'in_reply_to_user_id', u'favorited', u'user', u'geo', u'in_reply_to_user_id_str', u'lang', u'created_at', u'filter_level', u'in_reply_to_status_id_str', u'place']     <-- these are the keys tweets hold. but all of them seem to give the same error when tried

Comment: I know json from tweets are sometimes missing fields. I would try using `if 'id_str' in tweet:` before you append to `ids`.

Comment: I suppose I'll post it as a solution for any future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The json data from tweets are sometimes missing fields. Try something like this,

```
ids = []
for tweet in tweets:
    if 'id_str' in tweet:
        ids.append(tweet['id_str'])
```

or equivalently,

```
ids = [tweet['id_str'] for tweet in tweets if 'id_str' in tweet]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

tweets = []
tweets.append(
        json.loads('{"a": 1}')
)
tweet = tweets[0]
print(tweet)
print( tweet['id_str'] )

--output:--
{'a': 1}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 9, in <module>
    print( tweet['id_str'] )
KeyError: 'id_str'
```

And:

```
my_dict = {u"id_str": 1}
print my_dict["id_str"]

--output:--
1
```